# R Shiny dashboard does not render multiple plots

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I plot highcharter objects and store them in a list. When I try to plot them in a shiny dashboard it works fine for one page. However if I make it dynamic, i.e. varying number of menu and tabs dependent to input list, it shows nothing, just one page of plots, and other tabs and menus are blank. Here is an example:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(highcharter)

temp <-     lapply(list(sin((1:100)/10),tan((1:100)/10),runif(1e3),seq(100)/20),function(x)
  highchart() %>% hc_add_series(runif(length(x))+x))

plot_list <- list(`Menu 1` = list(`Tab 1` = temp,
                                  `Tab 2` = lapply(2:3,function(i)     temp[[i]])),
                  `Menu 2` = list(`Tab 1` = lapply(1:2,function(i)     temp[[i]])))

layout_column <- c(1,2) # columns per page

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Page"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar_menu_UI")),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("test_UI"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  ## create content for each page and tab
  for(n in seq(plot_list)) ## menus
    for(m in seq(plot_list[[n]])) ## tabs
      lapply(seq(plot_list[[n]][[m]]), function(i) {
        output[[paste0(LETTERS[n],letters[m], i)]] <-     renderHighchart(plot_list[[n]][[m]][[i]])})

  ## create menu items
  output$sideBar_menu_UI <- renderMenu(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sideBar_Menu",
                lapply(seq(plot_list),function(x)
                  menuItem(names(plot_list)[x], tabName=paste0("menu",x),     icon = icon("calendar")))
    ))

  ## assign content to page of each menuItem
  output$test_UI <- renderUI(
    do.call(tabItems,lapply(seq(plot_list),function(x) 
      tabItem(tabName=paste0("menu",x),uiOutput(paste0("menu",x,"_UI")))))
  )

  for(n in seq(plot_list)) ## menus
    for(m in seq(plot_list[[n]])) ## later change its location inside     switch?s
      output[[paste0("menu",n,"_UI")]] <- renderUI({
        temp <- do.call(tabBox,     lapply(names(plot_list[[n]]),function(tabname){
          tabPanel(title = tabname,
                   fluidPage(
                     lapply(seq(plot_list[[n]][[m]]),function(i)
                       box(highchartOutput(paste0(LETTERS[n],letters[m],     i)), ## get output plots
                           title = paste("Plot", i),
                           status = "primary", # primary, success, info,     warning, danger
                           solidHeader = TRUE,collapsible = TRUE,width =     12/layout_column[n])
                     )))
        }))
        temp$attribs <- "col-sm-12" ## set width to page width
        temp # check later the fluid page location
      })
})

runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

What I exactly want is to feed the app with a number of highcharter plots, and it should place and render them in menus and tabs.
Anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: your problem is that the plot ids are not unique.

Comment: There are total 8 plots. Id's are exactly `"Aa1" "Aa2" "Aa3" "Aa4" "Ab1" "Ab2" "Ba1" "Ba2"`, and each one is unique, I can't see the point that I'm missing...

Comment: It's actually the `renderUI` elements, that have overlapping `ID`s. `output[[paste0("menu",n,"_UI")]]` does not make sense in a two-stage loop.

Comment: Instead of second `for` loop, should I use some `lapply` inside `renderUI`?

Comment: Removing the second ‘for’ loop did it...  thanks!